# Java Crypto API equivalent to Ruby's OpenSSL (via encrypted_strings library)

Tags: java, ruby, cryptography, openssl

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted message that is encrypted in a Ruby web app using the encrypted_strings RubyGem library.

The encryption client code looks like this:

```
cipher = EncryptedStrings::SymmetricCipher.new(:passphrase => "abcdefgh"*2)
cipher.encrypt("howdy")
=> "jEUQrH58Ulk=\n"
```

The default symmetric cipher algorithm appears to be DES-EDE3-CBC (although the documentation for the RubyGem disagrees, but I will go with what the code says). So on the Java side I tried the following which I found online as an example of DES-EDE3-CBC usage of the Java Cryptography API:

```
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory


...
DESedeKeySpec k;
Cipher c;

...
k = new DESedeKeySpec("abcdefghabcdefgh".getBytes());
c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
decrypted = c.doFinal("jEUQrH58Ulk=\n".getBytes());
```

When I do this on the Java side I get the following:

```
Wrong key size
```

I also tried using the Java Crypto API with an initialization vector but didn't know what I should set the bytes to since I am not doing this on the Ruby side via the encrypted_strings library and it appears to be set in the C code interfacing with OpenSSL.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

I am using the bouncy castle JCA provider. I also tried DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (which corresponds with the documented default algorithm in the RubyGems documentation eventhough the code appeared to be referencing the previously mentioned algorithm, DES-EDE3-CBC).

I have tried reading around the Java crypto API, but the documents all seem to have the same code samples and not very many new clues. My sources include:

- http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/notes/javaxcrypto.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html

Comment: Please don't type exceptions and code. Always copy & paste. Your exception doesn't match your code, so you've mistyped one of them here on SO. There is no such class as `DESedeCipherKey()`.

Comment: If your implementation of Ruby is using OpenSSL you can always use a native wrapper to match it exactly. http://www.warnertechnology.com/Computers/Software/JavaOpenSSL.shtml this is ancient, but it gives the idea of it. There are a lot of commercial libraries that will do what you want, but I don't know of a free Java implementation.

Comment: @DanielChapman Thanks for the library link, I will investigate that avenue if/when I cannot figure out the Java Cryptography API.

Comment: @GregS Thanks for the feedback. I did initially copy and paste and updated my code to rerun the tests I had and thought I had manually updated the SO code the same way, but apparently I didn't change that line the same way. I will remember to keep things in sync better in future. I will update my question with all imports and the correct code as is momentarily.

Comment: That ciphertext looks like a base64-encode to me.

Comment: Older versions of Java only accept 192 bit ABC keys. You should create a key using "abcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh".getBytes("ASCII") or something similar to create such a key.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post it as an answer. With DESede you can use either 192 bit DES ABC keys or 128 bit ABA keys. Many versions of Java only accept 192 bit (24 byte) DES ABC keys. DES ABA keys is where the first and last key of the encrypt, decrypt, encrypt (EDE) operation is the same; in other words, it's the same as DESede with ABC, where C=A.

So to create such a key, you can copy the first 8 bytes (in your case 8 ASCII characters - using characters directly as key is wrong) of your key and concatenate them at the end. This would result in `"abcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh".getBytes("ASCII")`. Note that you should always indicate the character encoding, as the platform might as well use UTF-16 as default character encoding, resulting in a key of double the size.